# Is speaking the country's language fluently regarded favorably when applying for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

Let’s assume that Mike is a citizen and resident of a non-EU country, for example, Egypt. He has learned and practiced Italian to a fluent level online and/or by practicing with Italian expats. He applies for a Schengen visa in order to visit Italy for tourism.

He shows up to his visa appointment and proceeds to speak with the officers in fluent Italian. Does his command of the Italian language contribute positively to his chances of obtaining the visa or obtaining a multiple-entry visa?

Comment: The [Schengen visa code handbook](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2020-06/visa_code_handbook_consolidated_en.pdf) does not mention ability to speak the language as one of the criteria to be assessed, so *no, it would not make a positive difference* IMHO

Comment: @Traveller Perhaps it could be a factor in another criterion? For example, perhaps ability to speak the language might be seen as a factor in designating the person as potentially a "frequent and regular traveller" and contribute toward getting a multiple-entry visa?

Comment: Vast majority of people applying for Schengen visa don't go through interviews. It is a document based process. You submit your application and documents, and receive a visa or refusal. In rare cases an embassy may want to talk to you if they have some doubts. Normally, there is no interview. And in many countries, you don't even visit the embassy but apply through a third party contractor, like VFS.

Comment: Your travel history is the main factor that determines if you are a frequent and regular traveller.

Comment: @ThomasCruise Thanks for the info, I removed references to "interview" from the question. I mean the appointment to drop off the documents.

Comment: @hb20007 The people at the appointment to drop off the documents are not usually involved in the decision-making process in any way (they often work for a third-party company that has been contracted to handle administrative tasks, while consular officials from the country itself make the decisions on applications). It makes no difference whether or not they're impressed with you.

Comment: @ZachLipton I believe that this is not the case for smaller embassies, perhaps in countries with a relatively low number of applications.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.  When I went to immigration office in Bolivia I spoke to them in Spanish and got my document stamped, but the other people I knew who went there also got the document stamped without speaking much Spanish.  When I was there another person had his document rejected although he was a native Spanish speaker.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no specific language requirements. If you are just dropping of documents, it won't make a difference. The docs will be received by a receptionist who receives all sorts of documents for all sorts of reasons. The information what language you used at the front desk will never make it to the actual visa officer.

Even if they knew, this could go two ways. A visa officer mainly tries to answer two questions

1. Will the applicant return home after their visit or are they trying to stay illegally ?
2. Is the applicant non-desirable, someone we don't want to visit our country?

Language abilities would help you with question 2, but are actually detrimental for question 1. If you speak the language, it's much easier for you to stay and you have already invested time and energy into the country.

I don't have hard data, but I assume that vast majority of visa rejections is because of question 1.

Comment: I would like to add a caveat to anybody reading this. If visa officers happen to ask you, please do not lie about your ability to speak a language (or anything else) for fear that admitting the truth would be suspicious. Being caught lying is a guaranteed way to have your visa denied and even get banned from re-applying. Always answer all questions truthfully and you will be fine.

Comment: @hb20007: That's rule number one: never EVER lie to immigration officials. This can get you banned for a very long time. I was certainly NOT suggestion anything like this.

Comment: Why would language abilities help with question 2? If you’re coming on a tourist visa, the country will not care what language you speak, as long as you can communicate with locals, and English will do well enough for that in any Schengen country.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I believe he means that it's one way to help with question 2. Speaking English is also another way.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet in a lot of countries the locals aren't particularly happy about tourist hordes, but immediately see a tourist more favourable who has bothered to learn the language.

Answer (score 10):

For a tourist visa, language ability is highly unlikely to be an official factor in the assessment.

Unofficially, if I were an official interviewing you, I might even find unexpected language ability suspicious. Why would a tourist invest so much effort in studying for a short trip? Is it perhaps a sign that they intend to overstay and work illegally in the country?  Again, even in this worst case scenario I doubt this *alone* would disqualify you, but it might cause more scrutiny of the rest of your application.

Comment: 'I learned Italian in school and would love to have a chance to practice it' sounds like a defence to the above concern.

Comment: @user1908704 Learning a few words of Italian in school is very different from the "fluent level" mentioned by the OP.

Comment: In school you do not learn a language to fluent level. That takes a lot more effort (although there are exceptions who pick up languages easily.)

Comment: IMHO There's nothing suspicious about knowing an additional language.  And in the case of Italian, there are many Italian speaking enclaves all over the world due to post WWII migration.  A tourist from one of these locations might want to learn all about the old country.

Comment: @Willeke That’s a very broad generalisation, and not one I think is true in general. I took French for six years and Spanish for three years in school, for example, and am quite fluent in both as a result. And while it’s true that some of my fellow students were barely able to string together a basic sentence after six years, there were also many that were perfectly capable of having normal conversations.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I think your level of fluent is set lower than mine. Holding a conversation is not fluent as I see it and also a lower level than OP indicates in the question.

Comment: @Willeke Different people have different definitions of ‘fluency’ – personally, mine is very high (essentially I consider it equal to being a native-like speaker), but given that the question mentioned learning online and practicing with expats, that is clearly not the level the asker had in mind. I think most people would consider being able to get by monolingually in a language without significant problems to be ‘fluent’, which is about the level I described as “quite fluent” above.